# React - State not updating

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

When I click the button that triggers subscribe() I'm trying to change this.state.subscribe to be the opposite boolean of what it is.  I'm not even managing change the value of this.state.subscribed much less render different text when clicking the button.  I've tried replaceState and adding call back function.  Not exactly sure what I should be putting in the call back function though, if that's what I'm doing wrong.

```
 SingleSubRedditList = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

  getMeteorData: function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('posts');
    var handle = Meteor.subscribe('profiles');
    return {
      loading: !handle.ready(),
      posts: Posts.find().fetch(),
      profiles: Profiles.find({}).fetch()
    };
  },

  getInitialState: function(){
    var subscribed;
    return {
      subscribed: subscribed
    };
  },

  populateButton: function(){
    //fetch is cumbersome, later try and do this another way to make it faster
    var profile = Profiles.find({_id: Meteor.userId()}).fetch();
    if (profile.length > 0){
      this.state.subscribed =     profile[0].subreddits.includes(this.props.subreddit);
    }
  },

  subscribe: function(){
    this.setState({
      subscribed: ! this.state.subscribed
    }
      );
  },

  renderData: function(){
    return this.data.posts.map((post) => {
        return <SinglePost title={post.title} content={post.content} key={post._id} id={post._id} />
    });
  },

  render: function(){
    this.populateButton()
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.subscribe}>
          <p>{this.state.subscribed ? 'Subscribed' : 'Click To Subscribe'}</p>
        </button>
        <p></p>
    <ul>
      {this.renderData()}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

}
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the state using `this.state.subscribed = ...`, which you are currently doing in `populateButton`.  Trying to directly mutate the state like that will cause it to behave strangely.

You are also initializing `subscribed` with an undefined variable.  You should give it an initial status of `true` or `false`.

Comment: I think setting the state using '=' was what was doing it.  Thanks man.  Just one last question.  I'm trying to populate the button HTML based on something that is in the Profile collection.  But I can't do this in getInitialState because the data isn't available yet then so I made a function that I call in the render method that populates the button HTML and it's been working.  Since taking out '=' it's telling me Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). How do I populate button HTML in getInitialState or somewhere else?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Meteor, but as a general React design pattern, you should pass external resources in as Props to your component, rather than accessing them directly.  Because react will re-render whenever you pass new props to a component, you can be sure to initialize the state correctly when the data is available.